# Twitter Bootstrap - less.app compile error: "EISDIR illegal operation on a directory" when saving

Tags: compiler-errors, less

I'm trying to get my head around the less css processor for the first time but receive the following error when trying to save any of the Twitter Bootstrap .less files using less.app:

**Error: EISDIR illegal operation on a directory: '/path/to/less/output/directory'**

I have an output directory set on the bootstrap.less file only - is this a permissions error maybe?

Sorry if this is easy - any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Ben

Answer (score 2):

I think Less.app kinda makes you keep *.less files in /less/ dir, so try this structure:

```
/less/     <-- put all *.less files here
/css/      <-- default output path for compiled *.css files
```

The output path can be changed, but I use this structure as it's consistent and works instantly whenever you add a new project in Less.app.

Also, with Bootstrap you only need to compile boostrap.less file (it imports all the others), so uncheck the others in the app and make sure your HTML references just the /css/boostrap.css file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, was a little detail, when you compile with lessc in console you must specified the output file too not only the folder.

```
lessc app.less ../css/app.css
```